# OpenGL use pixel coordinate system

Tags: c, opengl, glsl

Alright, so, I'm using a VBO to draw a square (coordinates are `0,0 1,0 1,1 0,1`), and I drew it like so:

```
glTranslatef(200, 100, 0);
glScalef(200, 200, 0);
square_draw(); // Draws the square
```

This is without shaders. It works fine. However, when I want to draw it with a shader (for an image), it works, but it draws at the top right corner of the screen, completely ignoring the translation and scale.

Now I know why this happens: OpenGL has a coordinate system that sets `0,0` in the center, with `-1,-1` and `1,1` ranging the screen.

So what I want to know is: Is it possible to use a pixel coordinate system? As in, `0,0` is the top left, `1,1` is one pixel from the top left, etc...

Comment: This is exactly what the projection matrix is supposed to do. In your case, you need to invert the Y-axis (top becomes bottom) to produce your desired projection. But, understand that doing this will reverse things like polygon winding. So you'll need to change the winding direction of the front-face too if you cull polygon sides or do anything differently depending on which side is being shaded.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman How would I implement the projection matrix in an Opengl 3+ shader?

Comment: Something along the lines of: `gl_Position = ProjMat * vertex;`. The real question is how do you implement it in C, and that is up to you. Most math libraries will have functions to create 4x4 column-major matrices for things like Orthographic / Perspective projection. The most common library used (glm) is C++ only, unfortunately.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Yes, I'm sorry, that was my question. I don't know how I could implement this in C. How do I calculate `ProjMat` in C?

Comment: I would say, take a look at the manual page for something like [`glOrtho (...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373965(v=vs.85).aspx), it will show you all of the math you need to implement it yourself. Just know that OpenGL uses column-major matrices, so m[0] is the 1st row of the 1st column, m[1] is the 2nd row of the 1st column, m[4] is the 1st row of the 2nd column, etc. in a 4x4 matrix (`GLfloat m [16]`).